How do I built a connection to the internet through VPN app (pshipone) with urllib.request.urlopen?
I have seen this question but unfortunately, it has no answer. My problem is almost the same as this question.
I use the following code to connect to Telegram and run the Telegram bot code.
import urllib.request as urlLibReq

token = 'tokentokentoken'
url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/'.format(token)

cmd = 'getme'
resp = urlLibReq.urlopen(url+cmd)

Because I can't connect to Telegram normally, so I have to use a VPN. By running the VPN software (Psiphon), I can use the link (https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/) related to the robot in the browser and I get true response.

However, I can't get a response from the above code in Python.
So I decided to do the proxy settings based on the instructions I saw on the stack:
import urllib.request as urlLibReq

token = 'tokentokentoken'
url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/'.format(token)
cmd = 'getme'
ip = '127.0.0.1'
port=50225
httpProxy='http://{}:{}'.format(ip,port)
httpsProxy='socks5://{}:{}'.format(ip,port-1)
proxy_support = urlLibReq.ProxyHandler({ 'http': httpProxy,
                                        'https': httpsProxy})
opener = urlLibReq.build_opener(proxy_support)
urlLibReq.install_opener(opener)
resp = urlLibReq.urlopen(url+cmd)

But after making the settings, I can't get a response from the Telegram link. The following exception occurs:

Exception has occurred: URLError <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A
connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
respond after a period of time, or established connection failed
because connected host has failed to respond>

Interestingly, sites that open without the VPN, such as https://google.com/?query=test, can be answered with the proxy settings I mentioned. In other words, if I set url to 'https://google.com/?query=test', the Python code with the proxy settings and VPN software connected will return the correct response. So it seems that the Python code is connected to the VPN software with proxy settings.
I extract the port and IP from the log inside the VPN software.

What is wrong?
In addition, I have used the Request library as follows, but the problem persists.
resp = requests.get(url+cmd,proxies={'http:':'http://127.0.0.1:50225'})

I assumed that the problem was with the header, so I used the code below, but it still didn't work:
headers={'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req=urlLibReq.Request(url+cmd,None,headers)
resp = urlLibReq.urlopen(req).read()

Note: I use Python 3 in Windows 10.
